# Parse number from string with optional base

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

How can I parse numbers like `0x345`, `23423`, `0172` (possibly also `0b001111`) from strings?

I found the regular `QString::toXXX` functions but they take a base argument, but i want the base to be determined from the string in a way as it a C-Compiler would do.

I think there must be something present in Qt. But I only found the above mentioned or other method that explicitly take base (e.g. as stream manipulator).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `QString::toXXX` do what you want (except the binary representation):

> If base is 0, the C language convention is used: If the string begins with "0x", base 16 is used; if the string begins with "0", base 8 is used; otherwise, base 10 is used.

So just use `int i = s.toInt(NULL, 0);`

Comment: shame on me. i just saw all the examples and the interface of the function. Should have read to the end. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out, you'd only want to do this for binary numbers.

You have to detect the base manually (by reading the prefixes), by either:

- using `QString::left`, or
- using regular expressions

and then doing `QString:toXXX` with that base.